# How to bring SQL Server database out of "restoring" mode using SMO

Tags: sql-server, database, restore, using, smo

I'm bringing databases out of log shipping, trying to use SMO to do it. I'm attempting to mimic the following T-SQL using SMO:

```
restore database <database name> with recovery
```

Here's my code:

```
# select secondary_database from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases
$dsSecLSDB = $secInst.Databases["MSDB"].ExecuteWithResults("select secondary_database from log_shipping_secondary_databases")
$secLSDB = $dsSecLSDB.Tables.Rows

foreach($db in $secLSDB.secondary_database) {
        write-host "Restoring database (bringing online)..."
        $secRestrObj = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore -Property @{
            Action = 'Database';
            Database = $db;
            NoRecovery = $FALSE;
        }

        $secRestrObj.SqlRestore($secInst);
        write-host "Done with restore."
}
```

The error:

> *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyNotSetException: To accomplish this action, set property Devices*

The available options for `DeviceType` (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.devicetype(v=sql.105).aspx) are:

- LogicalDevice
- Tape
- File
- Pipe
- VirtualDevice

The problem is, I don't know which `DeviceType` to create. My guess is `LogicalDevice` but I don't know the value of it. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Consider simply using `ExecuteNonQuery` to issue a `RESTORE $db WITH RECOVERY`. The alternative is using SMO to painstakingly figure out what backup set is currently in use so you can set the `Devices` property properly, but why jump through hoops just because SMO requires you to (when no such restriction exists in T-SQL)?

Comment: Thanks.  It appears I'll need to go that way, was hoping someone had already done this before.

Comment: Probably someone has, but seeing as how SMO ultimately does nothing but execute SQL as well, you're basically using SMO for the sake of using SMO, which makes it nothing but a speed bump in this case. There are instances where SMO is much more convenient than plain SQL (for example, when you need to correlate lots of complex properties that can't be easily retrieved using a query or a statement would be very cumbersome to generate programmatically); this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same trouble.
I guess that the method sqlRestore is limited to a strong database restore, from a backup file/device.
Just bringing "online" a database with the status "restoring" (ie stand by db from log shipping or from a broken AG) seems to be possible only executing the "restore database  with recovery" with the invoke-sqlcmd applet.

Or if anybody has an other solution ...

Comment: Your reply looks like a comment to the question instead of an answer. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).